# SQL statement ignored error

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

Hello I'm trying to write a trigger that simply calculates a value based on a percentage and insert that into an attribute of an entity.

I keep getting a sql statement ignored error on the 7th line after the declare which would be `porcentaje := :NEW.do_porcentaje / 100;`

On this line I'm trying to assign the value of the `:new.do_porcentaje` divided by 100 to the "porcentaje" variable, do_porcentaje is an attribute on a table called "donacion" {do_porcentaje number, do_monto_aportado_$}, do_monto_aportado_$ is the attribute I'm trying to update with the value calculated in the variable called "monto" before the insert.

The sequence would be, before inserting the data take do_porcentaje and calculate what value I'm going to multiply by to get the percentage for example if I want the 15% of something do_porcentaje would be "15", maybe having $ in the name of that attribute is causing a problem? or maybe I'm doing wrong by opperating into data I havent inserted by using :new.do_porcentaje?

```
create or replace trigger calcular_monto_aportado
before insert or update on donacion
for each row
declare
porcentaje float;
costoinscripciones number;
nroinscripciones number;
monto number;
begin
  porcentaje := :NEW.do_porcentaje / 100;
  select into costoinscripciones from show where s_costo_inscripcion in (select s_costo_inscripcion from show where s_año = :NEW.do_show);
  select count (inscripcion.i_id) into nroinscripciones from inscripcion i join resultado r on (i.i_id = r.r_inscripcion)
              join calendario c on (c.c_id=r.r_calendario) join show s on (s.s_año = c.c_show);
  monto := porcentaje * (costoinscripciones * nroinscripciones);
   --  monto := (:NEW.do_porcentaje/100)*(costoinscripciones)*(nroinscripciones);
  update donacion d set d.do_monto_aportado_$ = monto where d.do_show = :NEW.do_show;
end;
```

Comment: "select into costoinscripciones" ... select what into...?

Comment: @OldProgrammer thank you very much